# Windows 7, ProblemStepRecorder, Bookmarks

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, bookmarks, problem-step-recorder

I need the quickest way to generate linkable bookmarks. I had an .mhtml output file, which was then converted to Word (web view) after using the built-in Windows 7 Problem Step Recorder. My  problem is that the output file generates a heading (normal text,  really) for each screen grab: Problem Step 1, Problem Step 12, etc. How can I, 1) search and highlight the the text Problem Step 2) as well as the subsequent number 1, 12, etc. 3) without capturing the colon, and 4) automatically generate bookmarks, which I will be referencing to from another Word document.

The context of why I am trying to achieve this is irrelevant. I need scan for text string plus two or three spaces for number string, then highlight all of them, then generate bookmarks. Not one by one, but batch bookmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Make sure pdf printer is installed.  Print to pdf,  opt in to generate bookmarks.